# Google Maps addListener and Jquery weird behavior

Tags: jquery, google-maps, listener

This is weird, perhaps someone can explain to me why this happens.

If I use the commented out `for` in place of the `.each()` then every marker displays the last storeObj's info when clicked. However it seems when using the .each() its good. All the markers are places where they should be on either, its just the click listener.

PS: If you want the full source code then just visit this URL: http://tinyurl.com/38x6yfe

```
        //for(index=0; index < store_array.length; index++) {
        $(store_array).each(function(index, this_store){
            //name  address address2    csz state   phone lng   lat   accuracy  brands
            //  0      1       2         3    4      5     6      7     8         9

            /*

            use this for FOR statement
            var name = store_array[index][0]
            name = name.replace(/\&/g,'&amp;');
            var address = store_array[index][1];
            var address2 = store_array[index][2];
            var csz = store_array[index][3];
            var state = store_array[index][4];
            var phone = store_array[index][5];
            var lng = store_array[index][6];
            var lat = store_array[index][7];
            //var accuracy = store_array[index][8];
            var brands = store_array[index][9];
            */

            var name = this_store[0]
            name = name.replace(/\&/g,'&amp;');
            var address = this_store[1];
            var address2 = this_store[2];
            var csz = this_store[3];
            var state = this_store[4];
            var phone = this_store[5];
            var lng = this_store[6];
            var lat = this_store[7];
            //var accuracy = this_store[8];
            var brands = this_store[9];



            var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lng);

            var storeObj = new google.maps.Marker({
                position: latlng,
                icon: gicons[brands],
                shadow: iconShadow,
                map: G_MAP,
                visible: false,
                title: name,
                zIndex: Math.round(lat * -100000) << 5
            });

            storeObj.id = index;
            storeObj.name = name;
            storeObj.state = state;
            storeObj.brands = brands;

            //add this store into the stores array
            G_STORES_ARRAY.push(storeObj);


            console.log('index =' + index + ' name = ' + name + ' storeObj = ');
            console.log(storeObj);


            //create a listener for each store
            google.maps.event.addListener(storeObj, 'click', function () {
                //G_MAP.setCenter(latlng); 


                console.log('index =' + index + ' name = ' + name + ' storeObj = ');
                console.log(storeObj);

                var contentString = "<b>" + name + "<\/b><p>" + address + "<p>" + csz+ "<p>" + phone;

                var urlstring = encodeURIComponent(name+' '+address+' '+csz);
                contentString += '<br><a href="http://maps.google.com/?q='+urlstring+'" target="_blank">Directions</a>';
                contentString += ' - <a  href="javascript:G_MAP.setCenter(new google.maps.LatLng('+latlng.toUrlValue(6)+')); G_MAP.setZoom(13);">Zoom To</a>';
                contentString += ' - <a  href="javascript:G_MAP.setCenter(new google.maps.LatLng('+latlng.toUrlValue(6)+')); G_MAP.setZoom(parseInt(G_MAP.getZoom())+1);">[+]</a>';
                contentString += ' - <a  href="javascript:G_MAP.setCenter(new google.maps.LatLng('+latlng.toUrlValue(6)+')); G_MAP.setZoom(parseInt(G_MAP.getZoom())-1);">[-]</a>';


                G_INFOWINDOW.setContent(contentString);
                G_INFOWINDOW.open(G_MAP, storeObj);
            });

            google.maps.event.addListener(storeObj, 'mouseover', function () {
                storeObj.setIcon(gicons["none"]);
            });

            google.maps.event.addListener(storeObj, 'mouseout', function () {
                storeObj.setIcon(gicons[storeObj.brands]);
            });
        });
    });
```

Comment: How come you are using `$(store_array).each`?! I thought [`.each()`](http://api.jquery.com/each/) accept only a jQuery object (not to be confused with [`$.each()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.each/)

Comment: I don't know? It seems to work good? haha. They probably have it do checking where if its not a JQuery object that it behaves like $.each()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To understand why this happens you will want to read up on closures in javascript.  Here is a Google Maps API specific [example](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/events.html#EventClosures), a more official [description](http://jibbering.com/faq/notes/closures/), and an [explanation](http://www.bennadel.com/blog/1482-A-Graphical-Explanation-Of-Javascript-Closures-In-A-jQuery-Context.htm) of how they're implemented in jQuery's .each() function